# Python 2.7 dictionary value not taking float as the input

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, floating-point

I am working with Python 2.7 and trying to insert a value which is a float to a key. However, all the values are being inserted as 0.0. The polarity value is being inserted as 0.0 and not the actual value.

Code Snippet:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import json
with open('new-webmd-answer.json') as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file, strict=False)
data_new = {}
lst = []
for d in data:
   string =  d["answerContent"]
   blob = TextBlob(string)
#print blob
#print blob.sentiment
#print d["questionId"]
   data_new['questionId'] = d["questionId"]

   data_new['answerMemberId'] = d["answerMemberId"]
   string1 = str(blob.sentiment.polarity)
   print string1
   data_new['polarity'] = string1
#print blob.sentiment.polarity
   lst.append((data_new))




json_data = json.dumps(lst)

#print json_data
with open('polarity.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(json_data, outfile)
```

Comment: when you printed string1 you see the expected output? Also it looks like you overwrite the keys in the dictionary with each iteration of 'd in data'

Comment: @user2682863 yes, when I print string1 I see the expected output. Yes, I am overwriting the keys. Before I overwrite I also add it the list.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Excuse the slack, your solution works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is currently written, you're overwriting the dictionary with each iteration. Then you append that dictionary to the list multiple times.

lets say your dictionary was `dict = {"a" : 1}` and then you append that to a list

```
alist.append(dict)

alist
```

> > > [{'a' : 1}]

Then you change the value of dict, `dict{"a" : 0}` and append it to the list again `alist.append(dict)`

`alist`

> > > [{'a' : 0}, {'a' : 0}]

This occurs because dictionaries are mutable. For a more complete overview on mutable vs unmutable objects see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

To achieve your expected output, make a new dictionary with each iteration of `data`

```
lst = []
for d in data:
    data_new = {} # makes a new dictionary with each iteration
    string = d["answerContent"]
    blob = TextBlob(string)
    # print blob
    # print blob.sentiment
    # print d["questionId"]
    data_new['questionId'] = d["questionId"]

    data_new['answerMemberId'] = d["answerMemberId"]
    string1 = str(blob.sentiment.polarity)
    print string1
    data_new['polarity'] = string1
    # print blob.sentiment.polarity
    lst.append((data_new))
```